# How to debug Algs4 programs with standard input file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I am practicing problems from [Algs4](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/) by running in eclipse with the debugger. For problems like [RunLength](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/RunLength.java.html) the program needs a standard input file when running the program. In code example the program is run as below in command line.

```
% java RunLength - < 4runs.bin
```

I tried running the same program from eclipse with both "Arguments" and "common" options of "run configuration", but the program keeps waiting for user input.

Please suggest how to debug this program correctly from eclipse.

[image: eclipse arguments]
[image: eclipse common]

Comment: Does disabling _Allocate console_ work?

Comment: @howlger Tried it now by unchecking Allocate, eclipse console gets disabled and the program keeps running in the background as before.